# Adding custom event to the process emitter

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this:

[image]

The code is like so:

```
process.emit('domainHavenRejection', 'unhandled rejection could not be pinned to a request/response.', e);
```

Obviously I am using TypeScript...is there a way to define a custom event on process, with the right type, or should I use a different event emitter?

Note that `'domainHavenRejection'` is my desired custom event name, but it could be any custom event, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

You can make compiler do not check types for emit() method.

```
(process.emit as Function)('domainHavenRejection');
```

Seems for now it is not possible to extend NodeJs interface.
But take a look at this issue https://github.com/typings/registry/issues/770